# From a MongoDB to an Android local storage

Tags: android, mongodb, cordova, local, smartphone

I'm working on an app.
It's a web app developed in Angular. I currently have a NodeJS backend and an online MondoDB database, so if I turn it into an Android app via Cordova, it works well (it's my final purpose).

But the data are sensitive and I can't afford to use an online database, the best thing would be to store all the data locally in the smartphone and create an export feature.

With this logic, I can't use my NodeJS backend anymore nor my database.

What could I do in order to replace my online database by the local storage of the smartphone? Is it even possible?

Writing into a json file into the local storage and make queries like I currently do with MongoDB would be perfect, but I have no idea how.

Thank you ! :)

Comment: In order to store all the data in your android app, consider using SQLite database. I am not sure how you are planning to get the initial data though. Are you planning to package the data along with your application's apk? In that case, you can just create a SQLite database file and can package it with your app.

Comment: Yes I plan to package the data along with app'as apk. SQLite seems to make it, but is it possible to query the data in json? I found Pouchdb, it seems to do it, any thought about it?

Comment: Yeah Pouchdb is a good option as well.

Comment: Okay I confirm that Pouchdb meets perfectly my need :)
Thanks for answering!